# rake task not found when create rails plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake, gemspecs

I'm trying to create a gem plugin with a rake task. I just commented out pre-generated file in tasks folder but when I run rake my_plugin, error came out that

```
Don't know how to build task...
```

here is tasks/my_plugin.rake file

```
desc "Explaining what the task does"
task :my_plugin do
  # Task goes here
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You run `rake myplugin`, but define `task :my_plugin`. You miss the underscore.

Comment: sorry for my misstyping, but that's not problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the custom tasks in your plugin's `Railtie`:

```
module MyPlugin
  class Railtie < ::Rails::Railtie
    rake_tasks do
      load 'tasks/my_plugin.rake'
    end
  end
end
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Railtie.html